# How to convert String 12 Hour AM/PM to String 24 Hour HH:mm:ss format in Apex?

Tags: time, format, salesforce, apex

I have String format: '4:33:34 PM' and I need to convert it to '16:33:34' String format in Apex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
String TimeString = '4:33:34 PM';
String Regex      = '(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2}) ([PA]M)';
Pattern p         = Pattern.compile( Regex );
Matcher m         = p.matcher( TimeString );

if ( m.matches() ){
    Integer Hours = Integer.valueOf( m.group(1) )
          , Minutes = Integer.valueOf( m.group(2) )
          , Seconds = Integer.valueOf( m.group(3) )
          , PmShift = m.group(4) == 'PM' ? 12 : 0 
          ;

    Time t = Time.newInstance( Hours + PmShift , Minutes , Seconds , 0 );

    System.debug( (''+t).substring(0,(''+t).indexOf('.')) );
}
```

Basically, this will separate the digits and AM/PM strings into hours, minutes and seconds, and uses them to build a `Time` object. Then it takes the string representation of that Time object and removes the milliseconds and time zone.